# In APIGEE, with a proxy URL, how would I find out which Product(s) is it a part of?

Tags: apigee

Suppose I know the proxy URL

> https://xxxx.org011.site.com/application/foo/v1/notifications/bar/orders

Is there way in the APIGEE tool where I can filter/search which product does this belong to?

PS: I've admin access on the APIGEE platform, just that I'm unable to figure how to search in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know the proxy name? If yes, it should be easy to search the product using Dino's [apigee-edge-js](https://github.com/DinoChiesa/apigee-edge-js) utility. Check this post on Apigee community for more details - https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Apigee/List-API-Products-associated-to-an-API-Proxy/m-p/170246.

On the other hand, if you do not know the proxy name, there are two approaches I can think of -

1. Assuming there is traffic to the proxy(if not, I suppose you could fire a couple of requests? they don't have to be successful) create a custom report with `traffic` as the metric(any metric should do), and proxy as the dimension. Under the filter, add a filter condition with `Name` as `Proxy Base Path`, `Operator` as `=` and `Value` as your basepath from your proxy URL. Save it and view the report, that should give you your proxy name. Once you know the proxy, use [apigee-edge-js](https://github.com/DinoChiesa/apigee-edge-js) utility to find the product.
   Note, there are bunch of other values you can use for `Name` under filter condition like `Proxy Client IP`, `Proxy Path Suffix` or `X Forwarded For`. Choose whatever works for you.
2. A less efficient approach; Assuming you store your proxy code in a version control system, I would suggest searching using the basepath like `/application/foo/v1` for example and find out the proxy name. Once you know the proxy, use [apigee-edge-js](https://github.com/DinoChiesa/apigee-edge-js) utility to find the product.